# Route53 hosted zones with same Subdomain but different prefix

Tags: dns, subdomain, amazon-route53, wildcard-subdomain

I am new to Route53 and have a typical issue handling the Subdomains as different hosted zones.
I have a hosted zone registered already and its name servers entry already done in my apex domain.
`abc.example.com`
Now, I wish to make another hosted zone with URL `def.abc.example.com`
Do I have to register another A-Record with the name servers given by the AWS Route53 for this hosted zone, Or should it work with the previous one, as I can always create `*.abc.example.com`. and that would be routed to the Hosted zone that I already have ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-to-resources.html#dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to have another hosted zone if you don't want one (Though depending on how many sub-sub-domains you have, one hosted zone per may make it easier to manage them). The smallest number of steps to get this working is simple to create an "A" record within the abc.example.com hosted zone named "def.abc.example.com" and point it where you want it to go.

If you choose to make another hosted zone, you will need to forward your name servers from that hosted zone by creating an "NS" record within "abc.example.com" that contains all the name servers from the "def.abc.example.com" hosted zone.